# Prove or disprove: if $f:[0, \infty] \to [0, \infty]$ is continuous and $f(x)\le \sqrt {x} +10$ in $[0,\infty]$...

Tags: calculus

> **Prove or disprove:** if $f:[0, \infty] \to [0, \infty]$ is continuous and $f(x)\le \sqrt {x} +10$ in $[0,\infty]$
> then there exists $c\ge 0$ such that $f(c)=c$.

I'm trying to prove this using the intermediate value theorem since $f$ is continuous, but It's not working, I'm trying to find $f(x_1)\le c$, and $f(x_2)\ge c$, so we get that there exists $c$ between them such that $f(c)=c$. 
But I'm having trouble with the upper bound $f(x_2)\ge c$, I'm starting to think this statement is wrong, but I know that I might just be messing up and not getting the idea. 
I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(x)=f(x)-x, g(0)=f(0)\geq 0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=-\infty$ IVT implies that there exists $x$ such that $g(x)=0$.

Comment: one could also produce a value here, if they prefer. if $x$ is at least, say, $25$, then $f(x)\le \sqrt{x}+10\le 15<25\le x$.

Comment: what do you mean by $g(0) = f(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

One can try to solve the equation

$$\sqrt x+10=x$$

on $(0,\infty )$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x) = f(x) - x$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$. We wish to show that this has a root. Suppose not.
Then, $g$ can not change sign. Noting that $g(x) = f(x) \ge 0$, we conclude that $g > 0$ on $[0, \infty)$.

Note that the equation $x - \sqrt{x} - 10 = 0$ has a real root, call it $c$. Then, $$0 < g(x) = f(c) - c \le \sqrt{c} + 10 - c = 0.$$
A contradiction.

---

Edit: The above proof actually shows that there is a root in $[0, c \approx 13.7]$.